# How to ignore GET parameter that’s the same as a CPT slug?

Tags: slug, parameter

I have a custom post type called ***newsletter***. At the same time, an implemented analytics tool (not related to my CPT) uses *newsletter* as a GET parameter to track some incoming links (and I can’t change this).

Say, I have

```
https://www.example.com/?newsletter=value_for_analytics_tool
```

This will lead to an 404 error page, as WordPress obviously tries to find a post in my newsletter CPT. But actually, I just want the main page to show up and keep the newsletter parameter for the analytics tool.

Is there any way to 'ignore' GET parameters, but keep my CPT working?

Answer (score 0):

You should always preface your CPT names with something to avoid stuff like this - common naming leads to conflicts.  My recommendation, so that you avoid this happening again would be to go and re-work your CPT code in your plugin/theme and use `myplug_newsletter` as the name of your CPT.  Obviously change the *myplug_* to something unique to you.

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for your answer! You are right in saying that one should check things for naming conflicts. In this case, my CPT was there first and then my customer implemented their tracking tool by themselves. And now it’s my honor to fix this again. :-/

So I was hoping to find a solution other than renaming my CPT, as there are many things connected to that. Something like "if there is _newsletter_ as GET parameter in the URL, just do nothing and keep the param".

I found this on the web: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19030021, but unfortunately this will break my whole CPT.

Comment: Sorry, I made the assumption that you were still in the early development stages and didn't realize the site had already been up and running.

Comment: The answer in the link you posted is taken pretty much from here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/request  I think you'd be able to modify that so that the request modification only executes if it's NOT loading your CPT.  So check if the query is looking for 'post type'=>'newsletter' and if not, run the filter.

Comment: this is not an answer. the issue can occur with any literally any post type name. its a legitimate issue that i haven't personally experienced but a proper solution would be nice.

Comment: Thanks this did the trick.